# How to wrap a complex object with one continuous image?

Tags: texture-painting, uv-image-editor

I'm hoping I'm not repeating a previous thread but I'm having a really tough time finding the right solution. I'd like to wrap an image (like an entire photo) around the surface of an object so that there are no breaks in the image or seams.

This is an example of what I'd like to achieve:
[image]

But every tutorial I've seen I have to unwrap the object, which then creates all of these seams and breaks up the image. And when I tried texturing painting it the image gets distorted. How can I maintain a smooth wrap of the image?

Thanks, guys!

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE. A question: do you want to paint on your model or do you want to use an existing image on wrap your model on it?

Comment: @lemon Sorry for the late response. I haven't had much time to play with my model recently. I want to use an existing image to wrap a model. the issue I'm having is that it is meant to look like a continuous, smooth, unbroken wrap around the model. @ Mentalist suggested using the "stencil brush mapping" which so far seems like what I'm looking for. Unless you have another suggestion?

Comment: @lemon perhaps to clarify a little better, the skull image with the flowers maybe isn't the best example. Let's say I had an image of a house that i wanted to wrap around the skull. I don't want the image to look like it was sliced up and kind of pasted back onto the skull. i want it to look like the entire house was simply wrapped onto the skull, like shrinkwrapping (but I believe in Blender shrinkwrapping means fitting a 3D object onto another 3D object?)

Comment: The idea can be to start from a planar surface with the image on it and to deform the plane to surround the skull, then project it. That can work or not as you wish and that will deform the image a bit

Comment: @lemon to clarify, are you suggesting to shrinkwrap the planar surface onto the skull or deform the planar surface to that it's kind of like a dome around the skull. If the latter is the case then you're saying to do like a "projection mapping" from the planar surface onto the skull? I actually have coming across that in my research so i just want to clarify. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're describing is UV Mapping. You need to create seams and unwrap a map of the 3D object. That doesn't mean the seams need to be visible. You can texture paint right over the seams and they won't show.
Image files are 2D, and this is why we must do this.

In the following screen shot, notice how I have painted green over a seam in Texture Paint Mode and on the 3D model it appears to be seamless? The break in continuity occurs on the 2D image instead, which you can see below.

[image: Texture painting over a seam]

Here's a .blend file of the screen shot if you want to examine it further.

[image]

You might be thinking "that's fine if you're painting, but what about photo textures?" There's a solution for that too. You can use "Stencil" Brush Mapping to paint an image onto your mesh (onto its texture, really), and also use the Clone Brush to blend the image across the seams.

Here is an example of how stenciling and cloning can be used to paint photo textures onto your 3D objects:

[image: Texture painting using a stenciled image]

This is the result of just a couple of minutes spent playing around, so you can imagine the possibilities.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. That seems like what I'm looking for. I guess the issue I'm having is with the complexity of my object. I'm using a skull like this [link](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/f3/8d/4d/f38d4d275259fde5d9d6d05638ea9b7d.jpg) and it's been a struggle to cleanly unwrap it and understand how the pieces fit together. Perhaps I'm just being too impatient? I won't be able to try your solution for a couple days but i will definitely give it a go and report back!

Comment: I've been playing around with the stencil a bit and it seems like what I'm looking for. I guess I just need to work on finessing and fine-tuning my unwrapping and stencil'ing skills. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Nice, glad it's working out for you. :-) There's tons of info on both those subjects on Blender Stack Exchange, YouTube, etc. Keep exploring and practicing and you'll get comfortable with it.